# Rails 4.1.2 - Reject nested attributes result being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a Rails form that has two types of nested attributes: `Pendencies` and `Address`.

However, those two are not obligatory fields and should be ignored when blank:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pendencies, allow_destroy: true,
reject_if: proc { |attributes|
attributes['status'].blank?      &&
attributes['description'].blank? &&
(attributes['pendency_type'].blank? || attributes['pendency_type'] == 0) }

accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true,
reject_if: proc { |attributes|
attributes['zipcode'].blank?                               &&
attributes['street'].blank?                                &&
(attributes['number'].blank? || attributes['number'] <= 0) &&
attributes['neighbour'].blank?                             &&
attributes['city'].blank?                                  &&
attributes['state'].blank? }
```

I have used `binding.pry` on both `proc`s to ensure they are running and they are. Both are returning `true` or `false` as expected.

Yet, once the model which hold those associations gets validated when calling `model.update`, it returns errors about the exactly same fields it should be ignoring:

```
@messages=
{:"pendencies.status"=>["não pode ficar em branco"],
:"pendencies.description"=>["não pode ficar em branco"],
:"pendencies.pendency_type"=>["não pode ficar em branco"],
:"address.zipcode"=>["não pode ficar em branco", "não é válido", "não possui o tamanho esperado (8 caracteres)"],
:"address.street"=>["não pode ficar em branco", "é muito curto (mínimo: 3 caracteres)"],
:"address.number"=>["não pode ficar em branco", "não é um número", "é muito curto (mínimo: 1 caracteres)"],
:"address.city"=>["não pode ficar em branco", "é muito curto (mínimo: 2 caracteres)"],
:"address.state"=>["não pode ficar em branco", "é muito curto (mínimo: 2 caracteres)"]}>
```

Sorry for the PT-BR in the messages, all it says is that the length is short and the field is invalid.

I would like to know how can I ignore those nested attributes so Rails would not try to save them.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't usually use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as it's fallen out of favor in terms of best practice, but it sounds to me like you need to add conditions to the validations in your nested models and skip those at the parent model in cases where you think they should be skipped.

Comment: @Nathan so you think I should also add a IF-logic to ignore validation on the nested models? It's worth a try. If `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is not really best practice, what is?

Comment: These days folks lean toward "form object" pattern. It's more OOP and in general easier to manage. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvL_aZt3zyU

Comment: @Nathan I understood the "form object" pattern, very useful, indeed, thank you. However, it is still not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, the answer was to consider conditional logic on the validators in your nested models. The form object pattern was in response to your follow up question.